# Bootstrap Tooltip is hiding the link that triggers it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I created a tooltip and here's the markup

```
<a href="search?id=34535" rel="tooltip" title="This is a Reddit App">Reddit App</a>
```

I'm triggering it via Javascript like this

```
jQuery('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[rel=tooltip]',
    placement: "right"
});
```

The problem is when my mouse leaves the link, along with the tooltip, it also hides the Link.

Comment: Can you recreate the issue on a jsfiddle for us to see it happening? My initial thought is that you shouldn't be specifying 'body' as the trigger but you should give the link a class or ID and specify that.

Comment: Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/LnVKt/

Answer (score 2):

It's a javascript library conflict with the tooltip plugin. You can fix it by using the following css to your link...

```
display: inline-block !important;
```

This will keep the link from disappearing but the real issue is the js library conflict.

Comment: I hope that works for you until you can resolve your javascript conflict. Use firebug to help you debug the issue.